# Using tomcat Trust-store in jetty for SSL

Tags: apache, tomcat, web-applications, jetty, jetty-8

I am planning to secure my jetty by SSL implementation. But I want to use my tomcat certificates, rather than the default jetty certificates. My jetty version is 8.x. I did a search on web regarding the ssl configuration on jetty. and i found [this](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html). Please suggest is it possible for me to use tomcat trustore instead of default jetty?

Answer (score 0):

A java keystore is a keystore unless you are using some specific Tomcat implementation of a keystore.  Jetty uses the default keystore bits that java itself provides, it should be a simple matter of configuring Jetty to look for the correct file, provide the necessary authentication bits to open it and any alias you may need to specify which key in the keystore to use.  That documentation is for Jetty 9/9.1 and may be a bit different than the specifics for 8. You can get to the 8 documentation through the hub:

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/

Comment: Thanks jesse for replying, yes i know that link was for jetty 9 . and i checked the link for jetty 8 earlier. here is the [link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_SSL). but what i want to know whether i should load my tomcat certificates in the JSSE keystore?

Comment: a cert is a cert, I am not aware of any specific to tomcat about them...but then I am really only versed on the jetty side of things

Comment: okay jesse, earlier i was using jetty 7 which did not support the use of tomcat trust store instead of default jetty certificate store. Recently we i upgraded  the jetty to version 8 so just want to know whether it is still not supported in jetty 8. do you have any idea regarding the deployment of jetty ?